# Evitar doble navegación entre las pantallas de una app ios con swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

Estoy haciendo una app en `IOS` con `swift` que cuenta con un menu lateral.

El problema es que si en el menu, clicko en una pestaña, me redirige hacia la nueva pantalla, hasta ahi bien, el problema es que si clicko mas de una vez me redirige hacia esa pantalla el numero de veces que haya clickado.

Eso se puede solucionar??

La navegación del menu y las vista las hago de esta forma:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var destViewController : UIViewController
    destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")//Home
    sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destViewController)
}
```

Comment: Creo que deberías controlar si ya has abril el menú lateral o no y permitirlo cuando pinches en la celda

Answer (score 2):

Una opción es preguntar si el controlador de destino es el controlador que está actualmente visible.

```
if destViewController.restorationIdentifier != sideMenuController()?.contentViewController.restorationIdentifier {

        sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destViewController)

}
```

Comment: Este còdigo no funciona porque `ENSideMenu` no tiene `contentViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Bloquea el touch de la aplicación una vez se inicie el código y vuelve a habilitarlo al terminar la animación o el cambio de vista, ya sea que lo habilites usando:

`- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated`

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que estás usando [SlideMenuControllerSwift](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift)

Podrías probar el cerrar el menú lateral apenas selecciones una celda. Así cuando hagas clic en el elemento automáticamente presentarás el nuevo ViewController y no tendrás la posibilidad de hacer más clics sobre la celda.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var destViewController : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")

    self.slideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destViewController)
    self.slideMenuController()?.closeLeft()

}
```

Lo otro es que debes verificar que celda estás seleccionando para saber a donde ir, eso lo puedes hacer obteniendo la fila de la celda seleccionada

```
let row = indexPath.row

if row == 0
{
 //hacer x accion
}
```

Comment: Estoy usando ENSideMenu